# Added dll reference for message box with "dont show again option", but resulting in file not found

Tags: c#, dll

I'm trying to use a msgcheckbox.dll file that supposedly gives a option to never show a message again.

So i added a reference in my visual studio 2010, and i placed the dll file right next to the classes of the program

http://puu.sh/dpdzh/3a7718c561.png

the code inside the main form is the following:

```
private void checkBox53_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     if (checkBox53.Checked == true)
     {
          MsgBoxCheck.MessageBox dlg = new MsgBoxCheck.MessageBox();
          DialogResult dr =dlg.Show(@"Software\Rhodes\","DontShowAgain", DialogResult.OK,"don't alert again",
              "gibberish message.","Alerta",MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information); 
     } 
}
```

However when he tries to create the MsgBoxCheck object, it fails with the following error

> "Could not load file or assembly 'CbtHook, Version=1.0.921.20088, Culture=neutral, 
>   PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified."

I enabled local copy on the dll reference, and other than that i have no idea if i'm missing something.

Can someone help this?

I think i might be placing the dll in the wrong folder, does it has to be on system32?

Comment: Is the name of the dll you added "CbtHook"?

Comment: Avoid using DLLs that you can't support.  Just use a [pinvoke declaration](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/shlwapi/SHMessageBoxCheck.html).

Comment: no, the name of the dll is msgboxcheck.dll

Comment: I'm trying to use that pinvoke declaration, but on the visual studio it says SHMessageBoxCheck does not exist in the current context. I'm a beginner, sorry.

Comment: dlls need to be in the gac or in the bin directory of the main program.  Are you not coping the new dll?  Did you put it in the wrong place?  Did you do a full build and not an incremental one?

Comment: @Hogan the dll is here http://puu.sh/dpdzh/3a7718c561.png

Comment: @ng80092a - That website is filtered by my office firewall.

Comment: @ng80092a - I would expect the dll to be in a `bin` or `debug` subdirectory, or both.  Is that true?

Comment: @Hogan it's in the debug folder, and in the folder with all the *.cs files

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66617/discussion-between-ng80092a-and-hogan).

Comment: It looks as though your msgboxcheck.dll requires another dll, called CbtHook.dll.

Comment: Ah.. ok i tried the dll file, and now it works, but it's old, i'll look for a newer solution thank you